# Hyper geometric series reference

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Can someone point out a reference for the proof of this identity? Thanks in advance.

https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric4F3/03/03/01/0002/

Comment: One fault of functions.wolfram.com is lack of references.

Answer (score 1):

It is equation (3.4) in

Whipple, F. J. W.,
On well-poised series, generalized hypergeometric series having parameters in pairs, each pair with the same sum,
Proc. London Math. Soc. (2) 24 (1925), no. 4, 247-263.

A very readable introduction to this type of results is

Andrews, G. E. The well-poised thread: an organized chronicle of some amazing summations and their implications, Ramanujan J. 1 (1997), no. 1, 7-23.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.